# Opening a local html file in the same folder

Tags: python, python-2.7

I understand this a pretty basic and stupid question but I can't seem to find a straight answer on here. I want to open a local file named 'test.html' that is in the same folder as my program in the default web browser. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use python webbrowser library.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html

```
import os
import webbrowser

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

webbrowser.open('file://' + os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'test.html'))
```

Comment: I don't really get why with this solution I am able only to open some html files, while for others I get "File not found". Could this be related to the length of the path?